# imshow displays the same picture multiple times

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to write a code to apply the gamma function to an image.

***[Original Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eel6rkqdndtb1t2/hw1_memorial.hdr?dl=0):***

[image: Original Image]

In my understanding (and hope I'm not wrong), you get a pixel and raise it to a certain value. In this case I've picked 0.5 (since it has to be a value below 1).

The code I wrote is pasted below:

```
memorial_image = hdrread('hw1_memorial.hdr');
[M, N] = size(memorial_image);

for i = 1:M
    for j= 1:N
        new_image(i,j) = memorial_image(i,j) ^ 0.5;
    end
end

imshow(new_image)
```

which gives:

[image: New image - result of the code above]

So the problem is when I try to show the image to the user, it doesn't show only one picture but, in this case, three of them in different tones. Why does it happen?

Comment: As requested here's the link to the image: [hw1_memorial.hdr -
 Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eel6rkqdndtb1t2/hw1_memorial.hdr?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `memorial_image` or `'hw1_memorial.hdr'` has three-dimensions representing RGB. When you use `[M, N] = size(memorial_image);`, the third dimension gets multiplied with the second dimension. Take a look at this smaller example to understand:

```
>> a= rand(2,2,3);

>> size(a)    
ans =    
     2     2     3

>> [m n]=size(a)    
m =    
     2

n =    
     6
```

By the way, your code can be vectorised and written in one line as:

```
new_image = memorial_image .^ 0.5;
```